# Textview not able to print next array in strings.xml

Tags: android

i need some help. Im trying to make a quiz app where the questions will change on the textview when i click the next button but when i click the next button my text view wont change to the next string on the array which in the string.xml

question.java

My onNextClick method where to change my question to the next one.

```
 public void onNextClick(View view) {
    if (done) {
        String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Questions);
        if (QuestionNo < (questions.length - 1)) {
            QuestionNo = QuestionNo++;
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
            t.setText(questions[QuestionNo]);


            findViewById(R.id.tickcross).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.correctornot).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.nextbutton).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
            et.setText("");

            done = false;
        }
    }
}
```

My onAnswerClick method

```
public void onAnswerClick(View view) {
    if (done == false) {
        String answer = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer)).getText().toString();
        String[] answers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Answers);
        String correctanswer = answers[QuestionNo];
        //gets the answer and correct answer from the edit text and strings.xml respectively
        correctanswer = correctanswer.toUpperCase();
        answer = answer.toUpperCase();
        //makes sure that the strings are lower case


        if (answer.equals(correctanswer)) {
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctornot);
            t.setText("CORRECT!");
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.right);
            mp.start();
            ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tickcross);
            i.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.weirdtick));
            answersubmitted();

        } else {
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctornot);
            t.setText("CORRECT ANSWER: " + correctanswer);
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.wrong);
            mp.start();
            ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tickcross);
            i.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.weirdcross));
            answersubmitted();
        }
        done = true;
    }
}
```

My string.xml

```
  <string-array name="Questions">
    <item>What is the letter A in the phonetic alphabet? LOLOL</item>
    <item>What is the letter B in the phonetic alphabet?</item>
    <item>What is the letter C in the phonetic alphabet?</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Answers">
    <item>alpha</item>
    <item>bravo</item>
    <item>charlie</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Hints">
    <item>A tough, domineering bloke</item>
    <item>Well done!</item>
    <item>Snoopy\'s mate</item>
</string-array>
```

hopefully you guys can help me correct or point out my mistake. thank you

Comment: Are you sure `done` is set to `true` in `onNextClick` method? And BTW, your code does not look too good.

Comment: yes, once onAnswerClick is done it will set done=true.im new to android , maybe u can help me make it better.

Comment: Hav u debugged the app and checked whether the questions array Havin the correct information??? And what is ur questionNo value above???

Comment: Check the done value ur putting it seems thats the nly error

Comment: guys after debugging and change the QuestionNo++; to QuestionNo +1; my problem is solved. Thank you very much for your reply :) appreciate it